# How to populate an IList collection using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We have a `User` class like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name;
    public IList Roles;
}
```

and a `Role` class like this:

```
public class Role
{
    public string Name;
}
```

When I serialize and then deserialize a `User` object using Json.NET I get a list of JSON instead of `Roles`. How I can configure Json.NET to have `User` object correctly deserialized?

**Updated :**
Please consider that changing the code is not an option because it's part of a legacy system and many system are dependent to this library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should provide a generic type parameter on your list, so Json.NET understands that you want a list of `Role`, like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

*Remember to add `using System.Collections.Generic`*

Since you haven't provided a generic type parameter for your `IList`, it'll effectively become `IList<object>` which in turn makes Json.NET treat its contents as `JObject`.

From the [Json.NET documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationGuide.htm):

> .NET properties on a class that don't specify a type (i.e. they are just object) are serialized as usual. When untyped properties are deserialized the serializer has no way to know what type to create (unless type name handling is enabled and the JSON contains the type names).
>   For these untyped properties the Json.NET serializer will read the JSON into LINQ to JSON objects and set them to the property. JObject will be created for JSON objects, JArray will be created for JSON arrays and JValue for primitive JSON values.

**EDIT:** If you for some reason don't have the possibility to add the generic type arguments, there is another alternative; by setting the [`TypeNameHandling` setting](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) to either `Arrays` or `All` (or maybe even `Auto`), Json.NET will include a `$type` property (and a `$values` property for arrays) in the serialized JSON so the serializer will know what type to deserialize it as. This will litter your DTOs with some extra metadata, but at least it's an alternative. I would absolutely recommend updating your objects with generics instead. This will benefit you in the long run.

Comment: The code snippet won't compile, IList<Role> needs a name.

Comment: The problem is this solution is not possible. The code is part of a legacy system and there are a lot of classes to be edited.Besides there are no unit test available for the source thus it's not easy to refactor it.

Comment: @Beatles1692 See the updated answer :) I don't buy the "no unit tests" argument. Adding generic constraints to collections should only harden your codebase and ease further development.